# Scala thinks that "import java.xxx" means "import net.java.xxx"

Tags: scala

When trying to compile the following scala classes for an LWJGL test of rendering an OBJ,

```
package net.y23k.opengltest.shapes

import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

/**
 * Created by yayes2 on 4/14/14.
 */
class Obj(file : File) {
  -snip-

}
```

and

```
package net.y23k.opengltest

import org.lwjgl.opengl.{DisplayMode, GL11, Display}
import java.awt.event.{WindowEvent, WindowAdapter, ComponentEvent, ComponentAdapter}
import java.awt.{Dimension, Canvas, BorderLayout, Frame}
import net.y23k.opengltest.shapes.Obj
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils
import java.nio.{IntBuffer, FloatBuffer}

/**
 * Created by yayes2 on 4/5/14.
 */
object Main {
-snip-
  }
```

maven throws the following error.

```
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:4: error: value awt is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.awt.event.{WindowEvent, WindowAdapter, ComponentEvent, ComponentAdapter}
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:5: error: value awt is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.awt.{Dimension, Canvas, BorderLayout, Frame}
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:8: error: value nio is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.nio.{IntBuffer, FloatBuffer}
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:72: error: not found: value closeRequested
[INFO]     while(!Display.isCloseRequested && !closeRequested) {
[INFO]                                         ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:73: error: not found: value newCanvasSize
[INFO]       val newDim : Dimension = newCanvasSize.getAndSet(null)
[INFO]                                ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:99: error: value util is not a member of package org.lwjgl
[INFO]   def v2dtov3d(v2d : org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f) : org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f = {
[INFO]                                                                  ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:99: error: value util is not a member of package org.lwjgl
[INFO]   def v2dtov3d(v2d : org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f) : org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f = {
[INFO]                                ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:107: error: not found: value GLU
[INFO]     GLU.gluProject(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, modelView, projection, viewport, screenCoords)
[INFO]     ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/Main.scala:108: error: value util is not a member of package org.lwjgl
[INFO]     new org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f(screenCoords.get(0), screenCoords.get(1))
[INFO]                   ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/shapes/Obj.scala:3: error: value io is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.io.File
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/shapes/Obj.scala:4: error: value nio is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.nio.file.Files
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/shapes/Obj.scala:5: error: value nio is not a member of package net.java
[INFO] import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] /data/Game Dev/OpenGL-Test/src/main/java/net/y23k/opengltest/shapes/Obj.scala:17: error: not found: value v
[INFO]     if (line.charAt(1).equals(v)) {
[INFO]                               ^
[ERROR] 13 errors found
```

From what I can tell, maven thinks that because my package starts with a "net.", the "java" package is in the "net." namespace.

P.S: Ignore the other errors, I'm just looking for an answer for the ones I just talked about

Comment: This is nothing to do with what Maven "thinks," it's about the way Scala interprets imports.

Comment: @RandallSchulz, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you have to prepend "`_root_.`" to your imports (http://www.drmaciver.com/2009/07/how-packages-work-in-scala/)

Comment: @Siphor Thanks! Mind submitting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend "`_root_.`" to your imports ( [post explaining scala import](http://drmaciver.com/2009/07/how-packages-work-in-scala))